# Como passar um CPF como parâmetro do tipo NSDictionary para uma chamada com JSON e POST?

Tags: json, swift, post

Olá, estou com uma dúvida. Preciso passar um CPF digitado pelo usuário como parâmetro na minha chamada POST para retornar com os dados dele. A chamada funciona com um CPF já cadastrado, mas só funciona se o CPF for passado diretamente como parâmetro, conforme fiz abaixo e do tipo `NSDictionary`. Como passar o CPF digitado pelo usuário como parâmetro na chamada? Segue a parte do meu código onde faço a chamada:

```
let mutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: URL)

mutableURLRequest.HTTPMethod = "POST"

let cpfPesquisa = cpf

let parameters: NSDictionary = ["cpf":"098.748.876-32"]

do {
    mutableURLRequest.HTTPBody = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(parameters, options: NSJSONWritingOptions())
    mutableURLRequest.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    mutableURLRequest.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
```

A constante `parameters` é passada para pegar os dados desse CPF, mas quero que no lugar desse CPF pré-definido seja o digitado pelo usuário (`cpfPesquisa`), como posso fazer isso? Desde já obrigada pela ajuda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente trocar isso:

```
let parameters: NSDictionary = ["cpf":"098.748.876-32"]
```

Por isso:

```
let parameters: NSDictionary = ["cpf":cpfPesquisa]
```

Ou então, como sugerido pelo iTSangar em um comentário, por isso:

```
let parameters: ["cpf":cpfPesquisa]
```

Comment: lembrando que o `NSDictionary` pode ser omitido da declaração: `let parameters = ["cpf":cpfPesquisa]`

Comment: @iTSangar Obrigado pelo lembrete.